# How to pass connection options like username and password in mqtt

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

I am getting `failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net:: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` this error when I fixed mqttprops.

I tried using these props

```
mqttProps: {
      host: "157.245.85.49:8084/mqtt",
      username: "tolomoto",
      password: "S36EeqD956UwGCYC",
    },
```

or

```
mqttProps: {
     protocol: "wss",
       host: "wss://157.245.85.49:8084/mqtt",
      port: "8084",
       username: "tolomoto",
       password: "S36EeqD956UwGCYC",
     },
```

or

**`mqttProps: "ws://157.245.85.49:8084/mqtt"`**

or
**`mqttProps: "ws://tolomoto:S36EeqD956UwGCYC@157.245.85.49:8084/mqtt`**

Please tell me how to solve it.

Comment: which js library are you using to connect with mqtt broker?